# How does OR and AND operators work together to set boolean value to a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to understand on how this line of code work. Example we have three variables `Value_1`,`Value_2`,`Value_3` initially set to `false`. There is another forth variable `main_value` which will be set to false if all the above three variables are still set to false (or) `main_value` is set to `true` if any of one of three variables is set to `true`.
This is the bash logic which works but I still am having a hard time understanding on how this actually works.

```
[ ${Value_1} == "true" ] || [ ${Value_2} == "true" ] || [ ${Value_3} == "true" ]  && main_value=true || main_value=false
```

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Grouping_Statements

Answer (score 1):

This can, and should be written like this:

```
if [[ $value_1 == true || $value_2 == true || $value_3 == true ]]; then
  main_value=true
else
  main_value=false
fi
```

or more POSIXly:

```
if [ "$value_1" = true ] || [ "$value_2" = true ] || [ "$value_3" = true ]; then
  main_value=true
else
  main_value=false
fi
```

Essentially if any of `Value_1`, `Value_2`, or `Value_3` are equal to true then `main_value` will be set to true.  If none of them are equal to true it will be set to false.  Things can get confusing when stringing together conditions like this.

---

You can see how it works with `set -x` though:

First is true so it skips straight to `&&`:

```
$ [[ foo == foo ]] || [[ bar == foo ]] || [[ baz == bar ]] && echo yes || echo no
+ [[ foo == foo ]]
+ echo yes
yes
```

First is false so the second is evaluated, second is true so it skips to `&&`:

```
$ [[ foo == bar ]] || [[ bar == bar ]] || [[ baz == bar ]] && echo yes || echo no
+ [[ foo == bar ]]
+ [[ bar == bar ]]
+ echo yes
yes
```

First and second are false so it evaluates the third, third is true so it moves to `&&`:

```
$ [[ foo == bar ]] || [[ bar == baz ]] || [[ baz == baz ]] && echo yes || echo no
+ [[ foo == bar ]]
+ [[ bar == baz ]]
+ [[ baz == baz ]]
+ echo yes
yes
```

All three are false so it goes to the final `||`:

```
$ [[ foo == bar ]] || [[ bar == baz ]] || [[ baz == foo ]] && echo yes || echo no
+ [[ foo == bar ]]
+ [[ bar == baz ]]
+ [[ baz == foo ]]
+ echo no
no
```

Comment: Nice answer. IMHO some script writers overuse '&&' and '||' just for the sake of compactness, when a well-placed `if ... ; then ... ; else ... ; fi` would make the script 10× more humanly readable.

Answer (score 0):

The `||` (OR) operator evaluates the expression on its left hand side (LHS). If the the LHS is TRUE, the result of the `||` becomes TRUE, and the right hand side (RHS) is not evaluated. If the LHS is FALSE, the RHS is evaluated, and used as the result of the `||`. This is often used in a "do this, but if it fails, do that" thought process.
Similarly, the `&&` operator evaluates its RHS only if its LHS is TRUE, "do this, if it succeeds do that".

Comment: The problem when you chain together multiple conditionals like this though is it will find the next matching conditional.  So if any of the first three are true the `&&` will be executed and if any are false the next available `||` will be executed.  Trying to chain logic like this is difficult and pointless so there isn't really a good reason to ever do it.

Comment: @jesse_b How "difficult and pointless"? How else would you express this? Multi-line nested `if`s, `else`s, `elif`s?

Comment: No nesting or elifs needed, see my answer

Comment: A big problem with this habit, which granted is unlikely to be seen here is if the `main_value=true` command were to fail, then `main_value=false` would be executed.    This logic can sometimes mimic an if/else construct but usually poorly.